# Merge every two lines from 2 files

Tags: awk, merge, paste

I would like to merge two files into a new one but two lines by two.
my two files looks like this:

File 1

```
'>dog-001  
atcatctatctat  
'>dog-002  
atcgatcgatctact
```

File 2

```
'>cat-001  
atctgtctacta  
'>cat-002  
atctgtatfga
```

Output

```
'>dog-001  
atcatctatctat  
'>cat-001  
atctgtctacta    
'>dog-002  
atcgatcgatctact  
'>cat-002  
atctgtatfga
```

I have tried some command with AWK and paste but I dont know how to indicate to take 2 lines.

Comment: Show us your attempt, it will help us see how much you already know and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: As such, I don't think Awk is ideal for this particular scenario.

Comment: Is there a reason your files are *almost* FASTA format?

Comment: The proposed duplicate has a pretty nice Awk solution, it should not be hard to adapt that to read two lines instead of one.

Comment: I have tried with awk:
awk '(NR%2){print; getline < "file2"; print}' file1 > newfile
and paste
paste -d \\n *.files > newfiles

yes its fasta format, with seq in the same order.

Comment: You have to adapt the code to read two lines from each. I don't think you can do that with `paste` but the change to the Awk script should be easy even if you are only just learning Awk

Comment: The single quotes before `>` are not allowed in FASTA proper as far as I remember the spec.

Comment: More like: `awk '1;!(NR%2){for(i=1;i<=2;i++){getline < "file2"; print}}' file1` Just modified your nonworking solution and did not bother to add the `ìf` before the `getline`.

Comment: thanks for answer. Yes for single quote it was beacause of format of the website...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You have indicated that's it is a duplicate, how can I access to the existing question?

Comment: @Nico64 Link is on the top.

Comment: Ho yes sorry. That was the one I was already looking for idea.